# android can't play this video that got by intent

Tags: android, video

Hi I'm trying to get video files' URI form the cellphone (both sdcard and internal memory ) with intent to play. but I face the error which says that: " can't play this video".

this is the sample address which I send to method of setvideopath
/storage/sdcard/sample.mp4

vwMainHome.setVideoPath(uri);
        vwMainHome.start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mp4 file having H.264 baseline encoding and still you are unable to play video in your android device then it might be problem in .htAccess file on server side. It might be zipping .mp4 file. few devices are able to play video by unzipping it and stream it but not in all device cases. You need to change .htAccess file on server side. Change in output filter and include file format .mp4 to exclude it from being zip at streaming time.

```html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|swf|mp4)$ \ no-gzip dont-vary
```

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by serverside but it is my cellphone and I want to play a file which is located on my cellphone. I tried different extensions like 3gp and so on ... and none of them worked